# Can not install Oracle database in Linux 7

Tags: rhel, x11, software-installation, oracle-database

I am trying to install Oracle database to Linux machine.I am getting error down below

Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set. Failed <<<<

I run commands down below but it still returns error. What should I do?

```
  [oracle@localhost ~]$ hostname
  localhost.localdomain
  [oracle@localhost ~]$ DISPLAY=localhost.localdomain:0.0; export DISPLAY 
  [oracle@localhost ~]$ xclock
  Error: Can't open display: localhost.localdomain:0.0
```

Linux Version

```
    [root@localhost oracle]# uname -a
    Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 
     11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Oracle Db Version 12.2.01

Comment: Are you trying to perform this installation on a remote server or locally?

Comment: On  local server.

Comment: You are sending the DISPLAY back to itself. You either need to forward your display to an x11 client, or run a desktop on the server so it has an x11 client